# hyperfine --prepare to clear harddisk caches on mac?

Tags: database, command-line, command, command-line-interface, benchmarking

First of all, I'm a beginner and only a mere mortal in the programming world so I apologize if I say some stupid stuff along the way.
I need to benchmark 3 databases so I'm using hyperfine. It works great except that I realised I need to clean the harddisk caches before each run.
Great, Hyperfine has the --prepare command !
In the documentation, they give an example for linux :
`hyperfine --prepare 'sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches' 'grep -R TODO *'`
I looked for one for a mac and found this : `sync && sudo purge`
My problem is that if I run `hyperfine --prepare 'sync && sudo purge'` I have this error:

```
error: the following required arguments were not provided:
  <command>...

Usage: hyperfine --prepare <CMD> <command>...
```

Does anyone know what the correct usage/command is ?
Thank you all !

tl;dr:
I'm trying to find the correct hyperfine --prepare command to clean my harddisk cache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...

I think you need to add the target you are benchmarking. That is the missing argument. You give prepare code to run first and then supply the argument.

e.g.

`hyperfine --prepare 'sync && sudo purge' 'grep -R TODO *'`

or in my case I wanted to clear the cache and benchmark a file:

`hyperfine --prepare 'sync && sudo purge' './day1/target/release/day1'`

(all on one line)

Tip was the error.

```
Usage: hyperfine --prepare <CMD> <command>...

error: the following required arguments were not provided:
  <command>...

<CMD> is 'sync && sudo purge'
<command> is the file I am targetting './day1/target/release/day1'

you were missing the <command>.
```

Anyway this seemed to work for me. I also used:

`hyperfine -N --prepare 'sync && sudo purge' './day1/target/release/day1'`

I added an -N flag as per hyperfile notes on shell interference. Don't fully understand that or the order of commands. Might want to play with that too.

I also used:

`hyperfine -N --prepare 'sync && sudo purge' './day1v2/target/release/day1v2' './day1/target/release/day1'`

to compare two files.

see https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine